# How to get insights of a facebook test page by using test user access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-test-users

I have trying for days to read facebook page post insights but get restricted every time with one or the permission error. I have taken read insights permission for that and have requested for manage_page permission as well. Hopefully these two will work out for me. For now, I am trying to read insights of a test page but **I am not able to create a page from my test user dashboard. every time I submit create page form I get HTTP ERROR 500.** Not sure what's going wrong. Any help regarding whole scenario would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Page insights are only available after a page has gotten a certain amount of likes (30, at the moment) - so you would have to create at least 30 test users and have each of them like the test page, before you could even start to test this. If at all possible, I recommend that you test this with a real page instead.

Comment: For real page i should have manage_page permission from facebook for my app. Right? Also I want to create a test page from test user which is I am not able to. Kindly suggest.